# Database slow query in Drupal select count(*) into @discard from `information_schema`.`PARTITIONS`;

Tags: mysql, drupal, partition

One of my page in Drupal is loading very slowly. When I checked with the slow queries list

```
select count(*) into @discard from `information_schema`.`PARTITIONS`;
```

This query is taking too much time to execute.
What is the use of this query and how can we reduce the execution time?

Comment: Query COUNTS the tables that is using table partitions and put that result into a user variable... read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitions-table.html  and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html... No you cant speed up that query because that table is a system table yout CANT alter it

Comment: Use transactions level unread commited